# ViewHelper for opening the page module view for a page

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

There is a ViewHelper for editing a record [be.editRecord](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/backend/latest/Link/EditRecord.html). Is there a ViewHelper for opening the page module view for a specific page? (This would be the same result you would get if clicking on a page in the page module.)

Comment: Reading the docs, <f:be.link route="web_page" parameters="{id: 92}">Go to web_page</f:be.link> should do so.

Comment: Actually, what I was looking for was <f:be.link route="web_layout" />