# How to open the web_layout module from a module and return

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I would like to open the "web_layout" for a a specific page from my backend module and then after performing an action, jump back to my module.

For this, I would like the action to open the web_layout to display a close button which will return back to my module, similar to the behaviour of using record_edit, for example.

1. Opening the record_edit form (with close button and working return URL):

   [image]
2. Opening web_layout - no close button

   [image]

I tried using this:

```
<f:variable 
    name="return_url" 
    value="{be:moduleLink(route:'web_mymodule', arguments:'{id:pageUid, action:\'listMyAction\',extension:\'myextension\'}')}" />


<f:be.link route="web_layout" parameters="{id:pageUid, returnUrl:return_url}" >
    <core:icon identifier="actions-document-open" />  
</f:be.link>
```

But this has no effect.

The return URL that gets generated looks good (as compared with others that work), but the page layout view does not have a close button, so I cannot jump back.

Comment: be.uri doesn't meet your requirement?
https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Be/Uri.html#be-uri

Comment: What I am looking for is to jump to the page layout view (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056869/viewhelper-for-opening-the-page-module-view-for-a-page) and then back to current module. I guess I can add the &returnUrl myself.

Comment: It seems to be possible to add the returnUrl to parameters. But then, there is no close button (which makes it impossible to return). I updated my question.